# How to move code changes from one branch to another in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have been working on a local branch and was ready to push the changes to remote branch A. Suddenly, I found out that the remote branch is closed for new changes and I will have to add the changes to a different branch B and push. Branch A has been merged to branch B and now all new commits will have to go to branch B. In git, I would do a cherry-pick to pick my changes from local branch A to B and commit. What would be the recommended option to accomplish this in mercurial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial offers the commands `hg rebase` (~ git rebase) and `hg histedit` (~ git rebase --interactive).

As you haven't pushed any of your changes yet, I recommend to simply use rebase:
`hg rebase -sXXX -dYYY` where XXX is the first changeset to move and YYY the changeset on top of which you want to place those changesets.

Depending on your mercurial version, both `rebase` and `histedit` might need activation in the [extensions] section of your .hgrc